# Difference between /(a|b)/ and /[ab]/ in JavaScript split() using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I just got in a situation where I wanted to split a string at each occurrence of `;` or a newline. I wanted to make sure this would not leave any empty array elements in, so I decided to use regex to include a string as long as possible.

I first tried using `foo.split(/(\n|\r|;)+/)`, but this strangely did not work as expected with double enters. Using the (for what I know) identical syntax `foo.split(/[\n\r;]+/)` did work as expected though.

Here's an example:

```js
var foo = "test;\nexample;\n\ndouble enters;\nand without semicolon\nend;\n";
console.log(foo.split(/[\n\r;]+/));
console.log(foo.split(/(\n|\r|;)+/));
//and to show that the matching strings are indeed equal:
console.log(foo.match(/[\n\r;]+/g));
console.log(foo.match(/(\n|\r|;)+/g));

document.write('<pre>'+foo+'</pre>'); //demonstrating what the string looks like.
```

So as you can see in your console if you run that snippet, the regexes *should* be identical here, since they `match()` the exact same characters. The output when splitting the string is completely different though.

The same goes wrong when replacing the matched characters with A and B for example (replacing all newlines with A, semicolons with B). Even then, these 2 regex splits have different outcome.

So my question is: does anyone know what causes this mysterious behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when you use a capturing group with the `.split()` method, the matched contents of the capturing group are included in the resulting array.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Capturing_parentheses):

> If separator contains capturing parentheses, matched results are returned in the array.

If you use a non-capturing group, the results will be the same:

```
foo.split(/(?:\n|\r|;)+/)
```

Example:

```js
var foo = "test;\nexample;\n\ndouble enters;\nand without semicolon\nend;\n";
console.log(foo.split(/[\n\r;]+/));
console.log(foo.split(/(?:\n|\r|;)+/));
//and to show that the matching strings are indeed equal:
console.log(foo.match(/[\n\r;]+/g));
console.log(foo.match(/(\n|\r|;)+/g));
```